# getting error while creating docker image for gateway application in jhipster

Tags: docker, maven, microservices, jhipster, gateway

I am trying to run this command: "`mvnw -Pprod verify jib:dockerBuild`" to create docker image for gateway application and I am getting the above error. I am reffering this youtube link:- "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4s6TmfWKkE". any help would be appreciated.
error is:

```
    --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:npm (webapp build prod) @ gateway-1 ---
[INFO] npm not inheriting proxy config from Maven
[INFO] Running 'npm run webapp:prod' in C:\Users\Janhavi\Desktop\devonfw\workspaces\main\gateway1
[INFO]
[INFO] > gateway-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webapp:prod
[INFO] > npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:prod
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] > gateway-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT clean-www
[INFO] > rimraf target/classes/static/app/{src,target/}
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] > gateway-1@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT webapp:build:prod
[INFO] > ng build --configuration production
[INFO]
[INFO] - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
[INFO] â?? Browser application bundle generation complete.
[INFO] An unhandled exception occurred: Transform failed with 1 error:
[INFO] error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
[INFO] See "C:\Users\Dhawal\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-mLs4Mr\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-16T10:48:42+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:npm (webapp build prod) on project gateway-1: Failed to run task: 'npm run webapp:prod' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDHvh.png)

Comment: Can share your docker file?

Comment: Does this error happen if you run `ng build --configuration production` in your project? You might want to look at the contents of "C:\Users\Dhawal\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-mLs4Mr\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606 you should update angular like in this comment https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22606#issuecomment-1039419367 or wait for next JHipster release and re-generate your gateway

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `npm run webapp:prod` alone?

I have the same issue on a generated project when launching `./mvnw spring-boot:run` at the end I get a similar error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:npm (webapp build dev) on project jhipster: Failed to run task: 'npm run webapp:build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 137 (Exit value: 137) -> [Help 1]
```

But `npm run webapp:build` is going well...

Comment: Running npm in your node environment is different from running it from maven using frontend-maven-plugin becvause it installs and uses the local version of node that is specified in your pom.xml and not the one that is installed on your PC